# Jquery chosen plugin not rendering for rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I have followed along with a blog to get the chosen plugin to work for my app. Currently, it's just rendering a normal html select tag. I believe the issue is with the jquery and not sure if it's also due to it loading in a modal? here are my pages and I'm just curious to know what my issue is.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.11.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha6'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
  gem 'rails-assets-chosen'
end
gem 'simple_form'
```

app/assets/javascripts/applciation.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require tether
//= require chosen
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
*= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'chosen';
@import "mixins";
@import "theme-variables";
@import "theme-mixins";
@import "variables";
@import "uikit";
@import "upload-widget";
@import "trix/dist/trix";
@import "actiontext";
@import "forms";
@import "hapyning";
@import "homepage";
@import "user";
@import "admin";
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('jquery')
require('jquery.initialize')
import UIKit from 'uikit'
import Icons from "uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons"
UIKit.use(Icons)
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<script>
  $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('.invite-email').chosen({
      allow_single_deselect: true,
      width: '100%'
    })
  });
</script>
```

This is all I am getting even when using the .chosen
[image]

Comment: try calling your `.chosen({...` function or `$('select').chosen()` in the browser console with modal open

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function`

Comment: If the page loads via a turbolinks request, maybe the jquery plugin isn't being initialized properly. If turbolinks is used you could try to use the turbolinks load event  to start your script like: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){...`